# Send data from the controller to the view using DTO and API in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I have a controller that is sending a list of items to the API and then I'm getting back the item response, it means that I'm going to receive for example if the item was not found or not valid it is working fine!! but I would like to know how can I send the dtoresponse list to a view from my controller and what I need to add in the view?

DTO

```
 public class ReceivedItemsRequest
    {
        public List<string> Items { get; set; }


    }
    public class ReceivedItemsResponse
    {
        public bool HasErrors { get; set; }

public List<ReceivedItemResponse> ItemResponses { get; set; } = new List<ReceivedItemResponse>() ;

    }

    public class ReceivedItemResponse
    {
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Controller

```
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Received(List<string> itemsList)

        {
            try
            {

       var dtoRequest = new ReceivedItemsRequest();
       var dtoResponse = new ReceivedItemsResponse();

       dtoRequest.itemsList= itemsList;
dtoResponse = await API.Post<ReceivedItemsResponse, ReceivedItemsRequest>($"items/", dtoRequest);



    return View(dtoResponse);  ---> this part I'm not sure
 how to send the list and what I need to add in the view or if I need to create a view model?
            
            }
```

Comment: Did you try to look at the documentation of [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) Did you notice how many overloads are present there?

Comment: Yes sorry that is the part that I'm not sure what I need to use and What I need to add in the view

Comment: RedirectToAction goes to a controller with a named action. If you want to return something to a View you use _return View( .... )_ and pass the data that you want to use as model for the view (in this case your list)

Comment: Ok and in the view what I need to add if you can show me the code of it would be great because I'm not sure which model add to the view

Comment: @Steve my question maybe where I'm confused is that I have a DTO I'm not sure if I need to create a View Model for it in order to send the data to the view or is not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I discovered you are returning a single record not a List in the controller. So if your API return value is a single record you will send to the View like below:

Your Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Received(List<string> itemsList)
 {
    ...
    dtoResponse = await API.Post<ReceivedItemsResponse, ReceivedItemsRequest>($"items/", dtoRequest);
    return View(dtoResponse);
 }
```

Your View:

```
@model Application.ReceivedItemsResponse
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Received Items Response";
}
...HTML Code on View here...
```

if you are expecting a list as your dtoresponse then on your View you would have:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.ReceivedItemsResponse>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index Item Response";
 }
 ...HTML Code Block here ....
```

Note that your controller does not change as long as you pass either a single record or list but your View does.